# displaying google map within a UIView Correctly

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, xcode8

I am using google maps with iOS.

this is my code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myMapView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368, zoom: 17.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    //mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.mapType =  .terrain



    self.view = mapView
    //self.myMapView = mapView



    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368)
    marker.title = "Eden VidanPeled"

    //marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
    marker.opacity = 1.0
   }
```

In the Interface Builder I have a UIView with the class GMSMapView. When I attach my map to the UIViewController, I get my lat-long coords. When I try to attact the map to the UIView, I get a different map, zoom level etc, 
as you can see in the photo below.

[image: the maps]

How do I get the UIView map to portray correctly?
p.s. I tried both viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear with same results.
Thanks

Comment: add mapview into your view like using addsubview function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already creating an `IBOutlet` for `GMSMapView`

It will create a map instance for you. So no need to create one more instance of `GMSMapView` and assign it to the class variable.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
     // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.

     let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368, zoom: 17.0)

     self.myMapView.mapType =  .terrain

     self.myMapView.camera = camera


    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368)
    marker.title = "Eden VidanPeled"

    //marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = self.myMapView
    marker.opacity = 1.0
}
```